# How can I exit the iteration as soon as if the condition has matched

Tags: javascript

How can I exit the iteration as soon as if the condition has matched, in the below example it still iterates

```
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
array.map((item, index) =>{
switch (item) {
     case "Three":
       console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " +item);
     break;
     
     default:
       console.log("Nothing matched yet !" );
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/um2bpLg0/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here.

The first is that map is intended to operate on all elements of an array. You cant really stop it going all the way. It also is expected to return something (whatever is mapped to). So map (or forEach for that matter) is the wrong construct to use if you want to stop early.

The second issue is the use of a switch statement. The break in the switch statement breaks out of the switch statement only, not whatever surrounds it. So in this case an `if` would be a better choice as `break` will break out of more than just the immediate loop.

Javascript comes with an array method [`array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which stops early if one of the elements meets a condition supplied in the callback function. This is a bit limiting in your use case as it just returns true if there is a match or false if there is not a match.

e.g

```
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
console.log(array.some(item => item == "Three"));
```

Here we just get the response true and nothing else with no idea of where the 3 was located.

We could improve on it with [`array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
console.log(array.findIndex(item => item == "Three"));
```

Which prints `2` and tells us the index of the string "Three" in the array. It returns -1 for no match.

Sometimes though you just have to go back to basics and use a regular for loop to get exactly what you want.

```
for (let item of array) {
    if (item == "Three") {
        console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " +item);
        break;
    } else {
        console.log("Nothing matched yet !" );
    }
}
```

Now the output is

```
Nothing matched yet !
Nothing matched yet !
Condition got matched ...!!! Three
```

Answer (score 1):

Higher order functions such as `map`, `forEach` will iterate over the entire array, if you want to `break` out of it at any time, please use a simple `for` loop or the `.find` higher order functions to break out.

In your case :

```
array.find(x => x === "Three")
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exit the iteration in a `map()` loop. If you want to do that, you should use a `for` loop.

```js
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  switch (array[i]) {
    case "Three":
      console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " + array[i]);
      i = array.length;
      break;

    default:
      console.log("Nothing matched yet !");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I know there's a better answer of this but i will post it maybe you find it helpful in something else

1. You can use `throw` keyword to throw error which will stopping `map()` of iteration
2. You can use variable which will stop the `map()` function when it's true

**Examples**

1. throw error

```
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
array.map((item, index) =>{
switch (item) {
     case "Three":
       console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " +item);
     throw new Error("condition is true"); //you can replace new Error() with something else like false
     break;
     
     default:
       console.log("Nothing matched yet !" );
  }
});
```

2. Using `check` variable

```
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
var check = false;
array.map((item, index) =>{
if(check === true) {return}
switch (item) {
     case "Three":
       console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " +item);
     check = true
     break;
     
     default:
       console.log("Nothing matched yet !" );
  }
});
```

- using `throw` keyword not recommended if there's another statements after your loop
- you can use the second way if there's some code will be executed after loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `for` loop: (check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) for the label)

```js
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

outerLoop:
for(var item of array) {
  switch (item) {
   case "Three":
     console.log("Condition got matched ...!!! " +item);
     break outerLoop;
     break;
   
   default:
     console.log("Nothing matched yet !" );
  }
}
```